# Promise unhandled rejection error from a promise that has a catch

Tags: cordova, promise, cordova-plugin-file

```
      function (fe) { //this is actually more promise chain, I simplified for the question
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                fe.getFile(fn, flags, resolve, function (e) {
                    if (e instanceof Error) {
                        reject(e);
                    } else {
                        reject(new Error(JSON.stringify(e)));//Lands here with file not found, says it's unhandled
                    }
                });
            }).catch(function(e){
                //never comes here despite erroring, and never enters catch later in the promise chain
                console.log(e);
            });
       }
```

I am not sure why the above code, when rejected for a file not found, throws an unhandled rejection, there is a catch statement there, and one later in the promise chain.

Any ideas?

This is the docs about file entry.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

My best guess is somehow the plugins javascript breaks promises?

The second strange part about is if I change the code like this.

```
      function (fe) { //this is actually more promise chain, I simplified for the question
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                fe.getFile(fn, flags, resolve, reject); //pass it reject, instead of handling it in an anonymous function
            });
       }
```

`Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Object]` error, but it properly falls through to the catch and is handled properly.

I don't know why adding a anonymous function would cause such a change.

Comment: If the promise inside your function rejects then you will catch it and rethrow the rejection which means that function will return a rejected promise.  So, you need to make sure that the caller of this function also has a `.catch()` handler.  You don't show the calling code, but that's where I see a potential problem.

Comment: Sorry I edited my code for clarity. It never actually enters the catch. There is also a catch earlier in the chain that I didn't show.  The weird thing is it does enter the catch if I don't use the anonymous function to turn the reject value (A custom object that mostly contains {code:1}) into an error object.  Almost like the reject can't work backwards through cordova callbacks.

Comment: What you're describing will not happen with properly functioning promises.  Not sure what else to say.